# External monitor not working properly on macOS Catalina

Tags: display, usb, catalina, hdmi

Before upgrading to `macOS Catalina` my `AOC 2369VM` monitor works fine with `HDMI - USB Type C` adapter. Once I installed `macOS Cataline`, the monitor immediately became badly connected or not connected at all.

I was trying to reset NVRAM, SMC, trying to boot in safe mode. I was trying to create new user in system. All the same..

I plug in cable into the port and nothing happens. And only then within 3-5 minutes monitor is connected.. Or not connected at all.. How to fix that?

This `HDMI - USB Type C` adapter works fine with other computer with `Mojave`

Comment: What mac model do you have? There have been some issues with HDMI on the Mac Mini 2018.

Comment: MacBook Pro 15 2017